# Use GoogleAnalyticsTracker in Android to track application version

Tags: android

I need to track app version. I'm using GoogleAnalyticsTracker.
Tried with:

```
tracker.setProductVersion(ver, subver);
```

but no version information appear as option in google analytics.
Is this information available or I have to use custom values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Analytics for Mobile Apps SDKs provide an interface for tracking activity within mobile apps and reporting that activity to Google Analytics. For example you can use this SDK to calculate visits, session length, bounce rate and unique visitors. Tracking mobile applications has some structural variations from tracking website pages.

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/android.html